# prawn will not install on production server using Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prawn, capistrano3

I have just added prawn and prawn table to my Gemfile and generated a pdf report. Everything works fine locally, but when I try to deploy to production using Capistrano I get the following error:

```
bundle stdout: An error occurred while installing prawn (2.0.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install prawn -v '2.0.2'` succeeds before bundling.
bundle stderr: Nothing written
```

I can ssh to the server, cd to the current directory and install the gem with no issues, but when I run the deploy again, I still get the same error.

Here is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.3'
gem 'bcrypt', '3.1.7' #for password encryption
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'will_paginate',           '3.0.7'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.10'
gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails'
gem 'momentjs-rails'

# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# JS runtimes
gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

gem 'carrierwave' #for file uploads

# gem 'prawn-rails' #for generating pdf docs
gem 'prawn' #for generating pdf docs
gem 'prawn-table'

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0' #testing framework
  gem 'factory_girl_rails' #creates objects during tests
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'capistrano-rails'
  gem 'capistrano-rbenv', '~> 2.0', require: false
  gem 'capistrano-rails-console'
  gem 'capistrano-passenger'
  gem 'capistrano-bundler', '~> 1.1.2'
  # gem 'capistrano-rvm'
end

group :test do
  gem 'minitest-reporters', '1.0.5'
  gem 'mini_backtrace',     '0.1.3'
  gem 'guard-minitest',     '2.3.1'

  gem 'capybara' #used for testing javascript with rsepc
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'capybara-webkit' #capybara driver that is javascript enabled
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  #gem 'poltergeist'
  #gem 'guard-rspec'
  #gem 'launchy'
end
```

Here is the error from the console:

```
DEBUG [ae525d2a]    An error occurred while installing prawn (2.0.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
DEBUG [ae525d2a]    Make sure that `gem install prawn -v '2.0.2'` succeeds before bundling.
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as deploy@103.6.212.246: bundle exit status: 5
bundle stdout: An error occurred while installing prawn (2.0.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install prawn -v '2.0.2'` succeeds before bundling.
bundle stderr: Nothing written

SSHKit::Command::Failed: bundle exit status: 5
bundle stdout: An error occurred while installing prawn (2.0.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install prawn -v '2.0.2'` succeeds before bundling.
bundle stderr: Nothing written

Tasks: TOP => deploy:updated => bundler:install
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing as deploy@103.6.212.246: bundle exit status: 5
bundle stdout: An error occurred while installing prawn (2.0.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install prawn -v '2.0.2'` succeeds before bundling.
bundle stderr: Nothing written
```

UPDATE:

by using `set :bundle_flags, '--deployment --verbose'` in the deploy file I was able to see that the issue was due to the ruby version on the server not being at least 2.0. Upon further investigation, the production server is using rvm (I was told it was rbenv), so by using the capistrano-rvm gem, I was able to get the  deploy to work. My problem now is that I can't get passenger to use the newer ruby version!!!!

Answer (score 1):

When you ssh to the server, you use `login, interactive` shell.
But, by default, Capistrano use `non-login, non-interactive shell` ( http://capistranorb.com/documentation/faq/why-does-something-work-in-my-ssh-session-but-not-in-capistrano/ )

So, the error could be because it's missing some env vars.

If I were to guess,

do you use rvm? if so, you may add the following line in deploy.rb

```
set :default_env, { rvm_bin_path: '~/.rvm/bin' }
```

Could you try?

Comment: I am using rvm locally, but rbenv on the production server. I have not had issues when adding other gems to the Gemfile, just the prawn one...

Comment: Sorry it took so longs to get back to you. I have just posted the output from the console of the error

Comment: Another update above - solved one problem but now have another, I need to investigate that one now...